# PHP and postgresql

Tags: linux, php, postgresql, php.ini

I am currently new to postgre and php (linux). I have updated postgresql from 9.2 to 10 and everything is working except for PHP. The php.info is still showing the old version of postgresql (see image), is there a way to change it to v10??

[image: screenshot if phpinfo]

Comment: It's version of `pgsql` PHP extension, not the DB. If you're facing problems, update the extension. But I suppose it will work just fine.

Comment: Can you please advice me how to update the extension? Sorry i am new to php.